# How to render twig macro in controller symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, macros, twig

i can't figure out, how to render a macro in Symfony 2 controller. This is how i can render a twig template

```
$this
  ->get("twig")
  ->render("AcmeBundle:Product:table.html.twig", array(
    "product" => $product
  ))
;
```

So i searching for something similar, but for rendering a twig macro. Thx for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Twig macro's are something inside a template. They are run whenever you render a template executing the macro.

Comment: You can (or at least, you *could* in 2.5) call a macro directly in a `$controller->render()` call, I've done it before, but I can't remember the syntax >.<

Answer (score 2):

Just create another "wraper" template, which would have only that macro in it. Something like

**macro.html.twig file**

```
{% macro sample(item) %}
   {# some code here #}
{% endmacro sample #}
```

**sample_macro_wrapper.html.twig**

```
{% from 'macro.html.twig' import sample %}
{{ sample(item) }}
```

**controller.php**

```
public function someAction()
{
      // ...........
      $renderedMacro = $this->get('twig')
           ->render('sample_macro_wrapper.html.twig', ['item' => $item]);
}
```